# complex number calculator in c using functions and structs

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

Kind of a continuation of [my last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69759454/complex-number-calculator-arithmetic-operations-with-struct-variables-in-c#comment123308029_69759454), I'm trying to write a complex number calculator using structs and functions. My program has to have a function for reading in complex numbers from user input, and it has to have another function for adding them. This is the function prototype I was given:

```
Complex read_complex(void)
```

This is the prototype I have to use and it can't be changed. Right now I'm trying trouble passing the values I scan in from the above function into my function for adding the complex numbers. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct Complex_ {
    double RealPart;
    double ImagPart;
} Complex;

Complex read_complex(void);
Complex add_complex(Complex z1, Complex z2);
Complex mul_complex(Complex z1, Complex z2);

int main(void) {
    char ent[50];
    Complex user1, user2;

    printf("Enter Add for addition, Mult for multiplication, MA for magnitude and angle, or Exit to quit: ");
    scanf("%s", ent);


    if (ent[0] == 'A') {
        read_complex();
        add_complex(user1, user2);
    }
    else if (ent[0] == 'M' && ent[1] == 'u') {
        read_complex();
        mul_complex(user1, user2);
    }
    else if (ent[0] == 'M' && ent[1] == 'A') {
        read_complex();
    }
    else {
    
    }

    return(0);
}

Complex read_complex(void) {
    Complex* user1;
    Complex* user2;

    printf("Enter first complex number: ");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &user1->RealPart, &user1->ImagPart);
    printf("Enter the second complex number: ");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &user2->RealPart, &user2->ImagPart);

    return;
}

Complex add_complex(Complex z1, Complex z2) {
    Complex z3;

    z3.RealPart = z1.RealPart + z2.RealPart;
    z3.ImagPart = z1.ImagPart + z2.ImagPart;

    printf("(%lf + %lfi) + (%lf + %lfi) = %lf + %lfi", z1.RealPart, z1.ImagPart, z2.RealPart, z2.ImagPart, z3.RealPart, z3.ImagPart);;

    return(z3);
} 

Complex mul_complex(Complex z1, Complex z2) {
    Complex z3;

    z3.RealPart = z1.RealPart * z2.RealPart;
    z3.ImagPart = z1.ImagPart * z2.ImagPart;

    return(z3);
}
```

(Large parts of the code are incomplete right now because I'm just trying to figure out the adding part). The current problem I'm having is that when I run the code, I get an error saying the user1 and user2 variables are uninitialized, and I don't know how to initialize struct variables.

Comment: `read_complex` should read *one* complex number.

Comment: printingwrong3434, Save time (yours and ours).  Enable all warnings.  `Complex read_complex(void) { ... return; }` should complain.

Comment: See how `add_complex` and `mul_complex` return a value of type `Complex`?  `read_complex` needs to do that, too.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of how pointers work.

The way you've written `read_complex`, you seem to think that the pointers `user1` and `user2` in this function automatically refer to the variables of the same name in the `main` function.  That's not how C works.

What you actually have is two uninitialized pointers inside of `read_complex` that you then attempt to dereference via the `->` operator.  You're also not returning anything from this function even though it's declared to do so.

This function is supposed to return a single copy of a `Complex`, so you should create one locally, read the values into it, then return it.  The return value should then be assigned to a local variable.  So this also means you need to call this function for *each* `Complex` you read.

Also, you may want to review how to multiply complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

> This is the function prototype I was given: `Complex read_complex(void)` This is the prototype I have to use and it can't be changed.

`read_complex()` returns 1 object of type `Complex`.  Use it to read 1, not 2, complex numbers.

Let use use that function to read and also create another function that calls it to read 2 complex numbers.

```
// Receive the address of 2 objects, 
// so this code knows where to save the result.
void read_complex2(Complex *a, Complex *b) {
  printf("Enter first complex number: ");
  *a = read_complex();
  printf("Enter the second complex number: ");
  *b = read_complex();
}
```

---

**`read_complex()`**

`read_complex()` becomes simple: read 2 `double`.  Check results.

```
Complex read_complex(void) {
  Complex x;
  if (scanf("%lf %lf", &x.RealPart, &x.ImagPart) != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  return x;
}
```

---

**main()**

Adjust like:

```
if (ent[0] == 'A') {
  //read_complex();
  read_complex2(&user1, &user2);// Pass in addresses of objects.
  add_complex(user1, user2);
  ...
```